# Clearing App data (Shared prefrence data) twice in a week

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, appdata

I Am developing App locking app. Right now I have set password to selected Apps. I needs clear password Weekly two times (Wednesday and Sunday at 1 clock). I needs to clear Entire app data. I searched in google but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharedPreferences to save data you can clear it using the code

```
mSharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply();
```

if you are using databases you need to clear the tables.

For time computation you can use the Calendar instance.

```
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
saveClearTime(now.getTime());
```

Comment: I used only shared preferences. I need to clear app data (passwords) weekly twice. But How Can I set a scheduler for clearing data.!!!! I didn't used any database.